# Why is BigQuery COUNT(*) of GROUP BY incorrect?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table with a unique integer `ID` and an `AuditUpdated` timestamp. I'm trying to divide it into groups of records by `ID` range like so:

```
SELECT CAST(ID / 100000 AS INT64) AS `Start`,
       COUNT(*) AS `RowCount`,
       MAX(AuditUpdated) AS `LastMod`
FROM `dataset.mytable`
GROUP BY `Start`
ORDER BY `Start`
```

This *appears* to work and I get the following for the first 3 records:

```
0, 25526, 2016-03-29 15:32:11.473 UTC
1, 65892, 2017-11-22 20:05:38.800 UTC
2, 48550, 2017-12-23 01:03:25.030 UTC
```

However, the `COUNT(*)` here is wrong. For example, I can run the following:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `dataset.mytable` WHERE ID < 100000
```

And the result is `61989`! Not only that, the `MAX(AuditUpdated)` is actually `2017-03-30 22:47:19.153 UTC`.

I have the same query running against the same table in a Microsoft SQL Server database and it works correctly. I can only assume BigQuery does things differently but I can't for the life of me figure out how!

Comment: Have you tried `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dataset.mytable WHERE  CAST(ID / 100000 AS INT64) = 0`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run this toy example in BigQuery:

```
select 
  cast(x/10 as int64) as bucket,
  min(x) as min_x,
  max(x) as max_x
from unnest(generate_array(1,1000,1)) x
group by 1
```

In [SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/divide-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), an `INT/INT` performs "[integer division](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IntegerDivision.html)", which returns the whole integer part of the result and discards the remainder/decimal places (aka rounding down).  Running `select 5/3` should return `1` and not `1.666667~` to illustrate this.

[BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/operators), on the other hand, returns a `FLOAT64` when dividing `INT64/INT64`

As noted in BigQuery [StandardSQL Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/conversion_rules), casting a `FLOAT64` to an `INT64` "returns the closest INT64 value" (aka normal rounding).  Your `1` bucket is actually counting all IDs between `50000` and `149999`.

If you want to replicate the SQL Server logic, consider making the following edit to your BigQuery code: `CAST(FLOOR(ID / 100000) AS INT64)`.

Comment: Fantastic -- I did _not_ realize that BigQuery did rounding when calling `CAST(x AS INT64)`. That is a mind-shattering revelation